# Algorithm not working on const_iterator for non-const object

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ from this book called Accelerated C++. A chapter has this function "split" which takes a string read from 'getline' and return a vector filled with separated words.

```
vector<string> split(string s)
{
    vector<string> ret;
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;

    iter i = s.begin();
    while(i != s.end())
   {   
        i = find_if(i,s.end(),not_space);
        iter j = find_if(i,s.end(),space);

        if(i != s.end())
            ret.push_back(string(i,j));
        i = j;
    }   

    return ret;
}
```

A slight difference is that the book version is collecting the string as a const reference. 
Compiler shows error that the parameters for find_if does not match. But when I change the parameter of split to const or change iterator to non_const it works.
I don't understand this behavior. I thought passing a const_iterator just means that the function receiving it can't modify the object. The object itself can be non_const in the passing fucntion. Please explain someone.

Comment: Please write the exact error which compler shows.

Comment: It [works](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fW6gZz) for me. What exactly are `space` and `not_space`? Also, the exact error message would make this easier.

Comment: @ Problematic       split.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > split(std::string)’:
split.cpp:30:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(iter&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, bool (&)(char))’
   30 |  i = find_if(i,s.end(),not_space);

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat  I edited my question.  I pasted the book version by mistake. space and  not_space are just wrapper for isspace and !isppace from C library.

Comment: Make `s` const, or use a `const&` alias to s, or use `cbegin()` and `cend()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a constant iterator, but it is initialized with a mutable iterator. That is a valid conversion. But no such conversion happens for second parameter of `find_if()`, it is value returned by non-const `string::end()`, hence the type mismatch in template parameter deduction.

Either of the changes you mentioned makes both iterators of the same type; const or non-const. Template parameter deduction proceeds without issue in such a case.